# Input text + Select + Bootstrap + form-inline: horizontal align label

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first question in Stack Overflow!

So, I'm trying to align (horizontal) all labels of my form, but, without success. My HTML is:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="form-filtro" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="filtrar-por">Filtrar por</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="filtrar-por">
            <option value="id">ID</option>
            <option value="id">Nome</option>
            <option value="id">Nome comercial</option>
            <option value="id">CPF/CNPJ</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="filtro">Filtro</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro">
    </div>
</form>
```

But, the result is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the bootstrap site and pasted your form code directly over the top of the example form-inline demo and things worked fine.

I did however encounter an issue if I manually styled the form to restrict it's maximum width.  It looks like your form may not have enough room to display and so the label is wrapping.

Check the styles on the form in your stylesheet, or on the containing element to see if something is restricting the size.

It would also help if you posted a minimalist reproduction of your issue.  ;-)

Comment: Sorry for not post the full code ^^. You are right. The problem occurred because there was not enough space to align controls. Thank you!

Comment: You could always mark it as the correct response.  ;-)  Glad it helped you out.  :-)

Comment: Just beside the answers to your question there should be a 'tick', which if you click, sets it to green and marks the answer as the correct response.  :-)

Comment: Done. Thaks again! :)