# HTML <select> with bootstrap Labels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have an HTML select, but instead of using plain text I would like to use Bootstrap's labels. How could I achieve this?

Something like this.

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option><span class="label label-primary">Primary</span></option>
  <option><span class="label label-info">Info</span></option>
  <option><span class="label label-warning">Warning</span></option>
</select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ng3GzXee6K8ELWYt2mDH?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469725/input-text-select-bootstrap-form-inline-horizontal-align-label

Comment: You **must not** use any HTML tags in `<option/>`. It's invalid for HTML syntax. But you can style or add the class to every option. @Piyush, this question is about something else.

Comment: @dragoste u r right  
 <option class="label label-info">Info</span>
    </option>
    <option><span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
    </option>

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a library like `Select2` (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#templating) which has some templating features.

You could use some `data` attributes on your `option` tags and show formatted `select` style elements thanks to Select2.

But as @dragoste mentioned, it's invalid to use any HTML tags within `option` tags.

The code would be something like this:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option data-label-class="label-primary">Primary</span></option>
  <option data-label-class="label-info">Info</span></option>
  <option data-label-class="label-warning">Warning</span></option>
</select>
```

And JS code the following:

```
function format(option) {
    var originalOption = option.element;

    return '<span class="label ' + $(originalOption).data('label-class') + '">' + option.text;
}

$("#select-example").select2({
    formatResult: format,
    formatSelection: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});
```

Comment: Okay, seems like that could work. But a little overkill for a simple feature. I would sooner drop the requirement. +1 though.